# Run concurrent builds on remote host in Bamboo

Tags: bamboo

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like only one build can be run on one remote agent  at a time.

I'm aware that there is the option to run multiple remote agents on a single host to have concurrent builds run on a host. Is there any way to run builds concurrently on a remote host without having to purchase a license with more remote agents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's right - you can only run a single build at a time on a bamboo agent (remote or otherwise).  If you want to run concurrent builds, you have to run multiple agents.

Comment: And this is probably due to their licensing model around agents. It's a shame too because it unnecessary complicates things. GitLab CI makes it trivial for a single agent (runner) to do concurrent builds: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html